# Proving a Complex Function is Continuous at the Origin

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

I'm currently reading up on complex analysis for a course I'm thinking of taking next semester. I've come across a continuity problem that I just cannot get my head around.

Let the complex function $f(z)$ be defined as follows:$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\mathcal{Re}(z)}{\left|z\right|} &\text{ for }z\neq0\\ 1 & \text{ for }z=0
\end{cases}$$

Is $f(z)$ continuous at the origin?

I think this is meant to be done by substituting in $z=x$ and taking the limit as $x\rightarrow0$ and the same for $z=iy$ and showing they are different, but I'm not sure. Could someone please clarify this?

Also, what would be the case, and how would you show it, if the numerator was $\left(\mathcal{Re}(z)\right)^{2}$ as opposed to just $\mathcal{Re}(z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instinct you are having is that it's not continuous. And right you are, both in instinct as in approach.

Let $z = t$. Then $\lim_\limits{t \rightarrow 0 }f(t) = \lim_\limits{t \rightarrow 0 }\frac{t}{|t|}$.

You might already know that this limit does not exist! (if t is negative it would equal -1, if t is positive it would be 1).

When one considers the Re squared problem this approach wont quite work. Now you could try to set $z = it$ in which case $f(z) = 0$ so it's not continuous in orgin.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Glad to know I'm slowly understanding this stuff.

Comment: Are you familiar with multi dimensional functions? Continuity in C is almost the same as $R^2$.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar, but I didn't really get the connection until about now.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, that function cannot be continous at $z=0$ since $f(iy) = 0 \; \forall y \in \Bbb R$, so you can find a sequence approaching $0$ such that the images of the elements [...]

The case is still the same for the second function you provide, since $f(iy) = 0$ again.

Note that this function doesn't use the complex product anywhere in its definition, so you can reduce the problem, if you consider it simpler, in a natural way to the continuity of a function $f':\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$

Comment: Thanks for helping me sort this out. I'm starting to get the hang of this stuff now...I hope!